# sar/sysstat output logs to a 2nd directory

Tags: rhel, logs, sar

We're running RHEL on one server and I need to report some stats about the machine. `sysstat/sar` does a great job but I need the logs to report starting with 6am until next morning at 6am and output the logs to a different directory other than `/var/log/sa`.

What I tried doing was this:

1. Created a directory `/var/log/sa/xlogs`
2. Created a file called `*sa3` (copied it after the `sa2` file) in `/usr/lib/sa` where I specified the directory where the logs should be generated
3. Created a new row in the `sysstat` file from `/etc/cron.d/` where I specified:

   `# generate a daily summary starting with 06.00`
   `06 00 * * * root /usr/lib/sa/sa3 -A`
4. Restarted the `sysstat` service

Now, it seems that this is not the way to do it as it did not generate the log. 
The usual log that is generated through `/usr/lib/sa/sa2 -A` is working.

My question would be: Is there a way to output logs from `sar` to a different directory while also keeping the logs generated by `/usr/lib/sa/sa2 -A`?

Comment: "and output the logs to a different directory than /var/log/sa" Why?

Comment: One of the developers wants the logs outputed like that. I wouldn't mind if the output is in the /var/log/sa if i can name them to something else (eg.sar*DD), but for some reason he wants them in the other directory

Comment: Can't you `rsync` the logs after the fact?

Comment: I've tried generating the log in the /log/sa directory for 6am but i also have to keep the log that is generated from 00.00 to 23.59. It seems it doesn't generate either way from the sa3 file. I'll talk to the developer and try to work out something else. Maybe use kSar and generate the log on the fly.